# Augment seperate values in observable of array - RxJS

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactive-extensions-js

I've been trying to tackle this problem for a while now, I would guess this is a pretty common problem but what I want to do is augment items in an array coming from an observable, and the augmentation happens with an observable or promiselike
So I want something like the following:

```
function augment(person: Person): Observable<PersonWithAddress> { 
    // does ajax call or something
}

const items$: Observable<Person[]>;

items$
    .do(x => {}) // x would be of type Person[]
    .flatFlatMap(person => { // person would be of type Person
        return augment(person); // this would return an Observable<PersonWithAddress>
    })
    .subscribe(peopleWithAddresses => { // peopleWithAddresses would be of type PersonWithAddress[]
    })
```

Is there some kind of operator for this, I get I can augment or map a single item emitted from an observable to something else coming from an observable with flatMap, but is there something like flatFlatMap or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` to do what you want.

It takes an array of observables (or promises) and, when all have completed (or resolved), it emits an array containing the last emitted (or resolved) values:

```ts
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin";


items$
  .flatMap((people: Person[]) => Observable.forkJoin(
    people.map(person => augment(person))
  ))
  .subscribe((peopleWithAddresses: PersonWithAddress[]) => {
    // ...
  });
```

Comment: Omg, thanks very much, I've been struggling with this for a while now. There are so many operators

Comment: Yeah, there are a few to learn. You might not have seen it, but there's a wizard at the bottom of the RxJS web page, which you might find useful: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/